# Unity: Can I use sprites for tiles to overlay a grid over a plane mesh?

Tags: unity, sprites, grid

I have a plane mesh in Unity. I have various other meshes on this plane (props) with tags that denote the areas under these props are unwalkable. I raycast, project and generate a grid on this plane and I have a map of walkable regions and unwalkable regions. This grid is a List of GridCell objects, I'm omiting the details.

Now I want to visually show this grid, so I attach a mesh renderer to the Gridcells and attach a mesh. Looking good.

My question is, can I use 2D sprites for these cells instead of a 3d mesh and still get the visual overlay on the grid plane?

Comment: Well i think its better to stick with mesh as both solution are almost same , except the fact that the sprite are unlit and mesh will be diffuse . Again which can be easily changed through material.